# sql syntax, count, group by and added in statement

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have a sql statement like this (using mysql 5.5.15):

```
select global_id, count(id) as group_count
from globals_lists
group by global_id
order by group_count desc;
```

and would like to modify it to support a subset with an in statement like this:

```
select global_id, count(id) as group_count
from globals_lists
where global_id in (3,4,5,6)
group by global_id
order by group_count desc;
```

I'll get as a result:

```
global_id   group_count
3           15 
5           12
```

but would like

```
global_id   group_count
3           15 
5           12
4           0
6           0
```

Is this possible? I tried a couple of having clauses but couldn't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little awkward looking, but how about?

```
select IDs.ID, ifnull(count(globals_lists.global_id),0) as group_count
from (select 3 as ID
             UNION select 4
             UNION select 5
             UNION select 6) as IDs
left join globals_lists on IDs.ID = globals_lists.global_id
group by IDs.ID
order by group_count desc;
```

Comment: I was afraid of something like this

Comment: `count(*)` will return 1 for a row that's not matched by the `left join`.  Count a column from the `global_lists` table instead of `*`.

Comment: any scaling concerns beyond a standard join with this? There's a lot more to this query and might just handle the non-returned values in ruby

Answer (score 1):

You could add a table with all desired values.  Either inline, like below, or in a temporary table.  Then you can use `left join` to match the number of rows.

```
select  lst.nr
,       count(gl.id) as group_count
from    (
        select 3 as nr
        union all select 4
        union all select 5
        union all select 6
        ) lst
left join 
        globals_lists gl
on      lst.nr = gl.global_id
group by 
        lst.nr
order by 
        count(gl.id) desc
```

Comment: is there any performance concerns with a query like this beyond a standard join?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `COUNT(id)`, use `COUNT(*)` so it will return a count even if there are none, assuming 4 & 6 do exist:

```
select global_id, count(*) as group_count
from globals_lists
where global_id in (3,4,5,6)
group by global_id
order by group_count desc;
```

Comment: is there a solution if 5 and 6 don't exist?

Comment: @timpone Yes, you need to UNION together the other literals.  Looks like it has been answered by another...